# Taylor polynomial Question

Tags: taylor-expansion

The function $f(x)$ is approximated near $x=0$, by the 3rd dgeree Taylor polynomial

$T_3(x)=4-3x+\frac{1}{5}x^2+4x^3$.  Give the values of $f(0)$,  $f'(0)$,  $f''(0)$,  $f'''(0)$

To find this, do I take the antiderivatives starting at the 3rd degree Taylor polynomial, and go back? I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you recall how to get a Taylor polynomial from a function?

Comment: Write down the Taylor formula and compare the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$T_3(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2}
f''(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(0)$$

so by identification of the coefficients of $x^0,x,x^2$ and $x^3$, we get

$f(0)=4$

$f'(0)=-3$

$f''(0)=\frac{2}{5}$

and

$f'''(0)=24$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(0)=T_3(0)=4$

$f'(0)=T_3'(0)=-3$

$f''(0)=T_3''(0)={2\over 5}$

$f'''(0)=T_3'''(0)=24$

We can't say nothing for highter degree derivatives.

Comment: Hm, similar can be done to approximately find $f(1),f'(1),f''(1)$ etc. with this idea.  :)  Intuitive answer.